# How to load all elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay. I have different `span` and have their `id` attribute set to dates in Y-m-d format. I am using countdown js to calculate each span countdown but my function only picks one date and apply countdown to it. It doesn't evaluate countdown for other dates.

```
<span class="timer" id="2017-10-1"></span>
<span class="timer" id="2017-10-2"></span>
<span class="timer" id="2017-10-3"></span>
<span class="timer" id="2017-10-4"></span>
```

this is countdown jquery

http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

and what I wrote in function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var time = $(".timer").attr('id');
    var timeLeft = time.split('-').reverse().join('-');
    $(".timer").countdown(timeLeft, function (event) {
        $(this).text(event.strftime("%D days %H hours %M minutes %S seconds remaining"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.attr('key')` will fetch the value of only first element thus `timeLeft` will be calculated based on first element.

Use `.each()` to iterate `$(".timer")` object and apply plugin `countdown()` individually on element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".timer").each(function(){
        var time = this.id;
        var timeLeft = time.split('-').reverse().join('-');
        $(this).countdown(timeLeft, function(event){
            $(this).text(event.strftime("%D days %H hours %M minutes %S seconds remaining"));
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: Perhaps also explain *why*.

Comment: I would rather declare time and timeLeft variables outside the loop, but the code is perfect.

Comment: this.id returns ''     it should be replaced with $(this).attr('id');

Comment: @ManojYadav, `this.id`will return id property of element. So no need to use `$(this).attr('id');`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to use .each: https://api.jquery.com/each/

It might look like this:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var time;
            var timeLeft;

            $( ".timer" ).each(function( index ) {
                var time = $(".timer").attr('id');
                var timeLeft = time.split('-').reverse().join('-');
                $(this).countdown(timeLeft, function(event) {
                    $(this).text(event.strftime("%D days %H hours %M minutes %S seconds remaining"));
                });
            });

        });
```

This is because you need to iterate with all the elements with the same class, you can accomplish this easily using .each().

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to apply element specific data to plugin options for that element iterate the collection so you can isolate specific element instances inside an `each` loop. Then get that element specific data and pass into the individual element plugin initialization options

```
$(".timer").each(function()
     // "this" is specific element instance
     var time = this.id;
     var timeLeft = time.split('-').reverse().join('-');
      $(this).countdown(timeLeft, function(event)               {
            $(this).text(event.strftime("%D days %H hours %M minutes %S seconds remaining"));
      });
});
```